# Given a point P and a circle, how to check if segment (0,0) to P intersects the circle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose I am at $(0,0)$.

Given a point $P$, I want to know if it is in the blue region or in the red.

In other words, I want to know if a segment from $(0,0)$ to $P$ will intersect a given circle.

I don't need to know where it intersects. I want to answer if this segment intersects the circle in the quickest way possible (less operations), for a computer program execution.

I'm wondering if there is a quicker way of checking this other than taking the distance from point to line and comparing with the radius.

[image]

Comment: Calculate the slopes of the two straight lines tangent to the circle using trigonometry.  The compute $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{p_y}{p_x}$ and compare.  (This just checks the wedge... not the *distance* from the origin.)

Comment: The obvious resultant of the system $$y=mx\\(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$ should have two real roots or one double root. When the two conjugate roots are non-real there are not intersection points.

Answer (score 3):

Given the center of the circle $C =(C_x, C_y) $ and its radius $r$, its Cartesian equation is

$ (x - C_x)^2 + (y - C_y)^2 = r^2 $

Now by connecting $P = (P_x, P_y)$ to the origin, the parametric equation of the line segment $OP$ is

$p(t) = t P = (t P_x, t P_y) $, where $ 0 \le t \le 1 $

Find the intersection of this line segment with the circle by substituting the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $p(t)$ into the equation of the circle, this gives

$( t P_x - C_x)^2 + (t P_y - C_y)^2 = r^2 $

And this simplifies to

$ a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0 = 0 $

with

$ a_2 = P_x^2 + P_y^2 , \ a_1 = - 2 ( P_x C_x + P_y C_y ) , \ a_0 = C_x^2 + C_y^2 - r^2 $

The discriminant of this quadratic equation is

$ \Delta = a_1^2 - 4 \ a_2 \ a_0 $

If $\Delta \lt 0 $ then there is no intersection between the segment and the circle, so $P$ must be in the blue region.

If $\Delta = 0 $ , then there is only one solution for $t$, and that solution is

$ t_0 = - \dfrac{a_1}{2 a_2} $

In this case, if $t_0 \gt 1$ then $P$ is in the blue region, otherwise, $P$ is on the straight boundary between the red region and the blue region

If $\Delta \gt 0 $, then there are two solutions

$ t_1 = \dfrac{ - a_1 - \sqrt{\Delta} }{2 a_2} $

$ t_2 = \dfrac{ - a_1 + \sqrt{\Delta} }{2 a_2 } $

These two values correspond to the intersections of the line segment (or its extension) with the circle.  Since $a_2 \gt 0 $ , then $t_1 \lt t_2 $.

Now, if $t_1 \lt 1$ then $P$ lies in the red region.  If $t_1 \gt 1$ then $P$ lies in the blue region.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this problem splitting it in two steps. The first step to cover the inner part of the circle and the second step to cover the outer part.

[image]

**Step 1**: Checking $distance(P,O) \le r$. This would cover this region:

[image]

**Step 2**: To cover the remaining region, I needed to take the distance from the line formed by $(0,0)$ and $P$ and the circle's origin $O$. For this, I used the vector notation of a line:

$$P_t = P_0 + dt$$

Where $P_0$ is a point in the line, $d$ is the normalized directional vector of the line and $P_t$ is the target point in time $t$.

Given this notation, the distance between the line and $O$ can be evaluated by the formula

$$distance(P_0 + dt, O) = ||(O-P_0) - ((O-P_0)\cdot D)D||$$

As we know $(0,0)$ is in the line, we could reduce it to

$$distance(P_0 + dt, O) = ||O - (O\cdot D)D||$$

We know that the direction $d$ is $P - (0,0)$ normalized, which is just $\hat{P}$ (seeing $P$ as a vector and normalizing it).

$$distance(P_0 + dt, O) = ||O - (O\cdot \hat{P})\hat{P}||$$

So, in the end, we ask $||O - (O\cdot \hat{P})\hat{P}|| \le r$ and if $||P|| >= ||O||$. This would cover this region:

[image]

---

In a nutshell, $P$ is in the red region if

- $distance(P,O) \le r$ or
- $||O - (O\cdot \hat{P})\hat{P}|| \le r$ and if $||P|| >= ||O||$

Answer (score 0):

say point $P$ is $(a, b)$.

What is the equation of the line passing through $(a, b)$ and $(0, 0)$. Must be $y = mx$, where $m$ is the slope.

You know the equation of the circle: $(x - c)^2 + (y - d)^2 = r^2$

If they *intersect* there must be a point (u, v) that satisfies *both* equations.